# How to change frontpage layout

Tags: magento1.9.3

I'm having **some serious issues** finding the place where i can change the **image** for the diffrent boxes i have on my frontpage. I've been under CMS --> Pages --> Design, but i dont seem to find the place, where i can switch out the image i want showcased.

The website is: www.h-copenahgen.com

Please see attached picture:

[image]

Comment: can not access website

Comment: It might be at cms->page->home page->content.
                                      Or
cms->page->home page->design tab->Layout update xml
                                        Or 
at app/design/frontend/theme/layout/cms.xml <cms_index_index>

Answer (score 0):

It might be at

**cms->page->home page->content**.
      *Or* 
**cms->page->home page->design tab->Layout update xml** 
            *Or*

at app/design/frontend/theme/layout/cms.xml

```
     <cms_index_index>

      </cms_index_index>
```